# How to compare the structure and type of two hash tables, not the values

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

I am trying to compare the structure of two hash tables. I want to see if any given hash table is a subset of a master table.

Example of valid sub-table:

```
master_table = {a: String, b: Object, c: { nested_a: Integer, nested_b: Integer} }

my_table     = {a: 'cool value', c: {nested_b: 540}
```

Example of invalid sub-table

```
my_table     = {a: WrongType.new}
```

or

```
my_table     = {a: 'cool value', new_key: "I don't belong here!"}
```

Edit: If it looks somewhat like a duck and quacks kinda like a duck, then I will accept it as a duck.

I have an data driven application where user have to provide a config file that defines the application's behavior. I want to make sure that users' configuration files match the structure and types defined in the master config file.

In regards to Sergio Tulentsev's comment, the issue above is that in the first example of an invalid sub-table, :a's type is not valid according to the master table. In the second case, there exists a Key that is not present in the master table and therefor incorrect.

Comment: So, what's the problem here?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If this isn't just a coding exercise, I'd re-evaluate whether `master_table` is best represented by a hash or would be better suited as an actual object that knows how to validate a hash (`my_table`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
def valid?(master_table, my_table)
  my_table.all? do |k,v|
    case master_table.key?(k)
    when true      
      mv = master_table[k]
      case v
      when Hash then mv.is_a?(Hash) && valid?(mv, v)
      else mv.is_a?(Class) && v.is_a?(mv)
      end
    else false
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
master_table = {a: String, b: Object, c: {nested_a: Integer, nested_b: Integer}}

my_table = {a: 'cool value', c: {nested_b: 540}}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> true

my_table = {a: 'cool value', new_key: "I don't belong here!"}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> false

my_table = {a: 'cool value', new_key: "I don't belong here!"}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> false

my_table = {a: 'cool value', c: 42}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> false
```

```
master_table = {a: String, b: Object, c: {nested_a: {nested_b:
  {nested_c: Integer}}}}

my_table = {a: 'cool value', b: [1,2,3], c: {nested_a: {nested_b:
  {nested_c: 42}}}}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> true

my_table = {a: 'cool value', b: [1,2,3], c: {nested_a: {nested_b:
  {nested_c: 'cat'}}}}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> false

my_table = {a: 'cool value', b: [1,2,3], c: {nested_a: {nested_b: 42}}}
valid?(master_table, my_table)
  #=> false
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was bored, so here you go. Monkey-patching (defining method on `Hash` class from standard lib) is optional, your new homework would be to get rid of it.

```
class Hash
  def structural_subset_of?(master)
    each_pair do |key, value|
      expected_type = master[key]
      return false unless expected_type

      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        return false unless value.structural_subset_of?(master[key])
      else
        return false unless value.is_a?(expected_type)
      end
    end
    true
  end
end

master = {a: String, b: Object, c: { nested_a: Integer, nested_b: Integer} }

valid     = {a: 'cool value', c: {nested_b: 540} }
invalid1     = {a: Object.new}
invalid2     = {a: 'cool value', new_key: "I don't belong here!"}

valid.structural_subset_of?(master) # => true
invalid1.structural_subset_of?(master) # => false
invalid2.structural_subset_of?(master) # => false
```

Comment: Looks good, Sergio. It works with the additional examples in my answer.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. `{a: 'cat', c: 42}.structural_subset_of?(master) #=> TypeError: class or module required`. Easy fix. Reply not req'd; I'll delete this comment...

Comment: Thanks man. We have to leave _something_ for him to do, don't we? :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot more than comparing hash structure. You're comparing structure in a very specific way (subset). You're also checking validity of the actual values. That's a lot to offload to `Hash`. If you have any leverage with `master_table`, I'd extract some actual objects to do the work for you.

Here is an example solution with objects.

I started by creating some validation objects:

```
class KlassValidation
  attr_reader :klass

  def initialize(klass)
    @klass = klass
  end

  def valid?(hash, key)
    return true unless hash.keys.include?(key)
    hash[key].is_a? klass
  end
end

string_validation = KlassValidation.new(String)
object_validation = KlassValidation.new(Object)
integer_validation = KlassValidation.new(Integer)

class HashValidation
  attr_reader :validations

  def initialize(validations)
    @validations = validations
  end

  def valid?(hash, key=nil)
    hash_to_validate = key ? hash[key] : hash
    return true unless hash_to_validate
    return false if invalid_keys?(hash_to_validate)
    validations.all? { |key, validation| validation.valid?(hash_to_validate, key) }
  end

  def invalid_keys?(hash)
    (hash.keys - validations.keys).any?
  end
end
```

Then `master_table` uses these objects:

```
master_table = HashValidation.new(a: string_validation, b: object_validation, c: HashValidation.new(nested_a: integer_validation, nested_b: integer_validation))
```

Checking validity of a hash is then just a matter of passing it to the `valid?` method of `master_table`.

```
test_cases = [
  { valid: true, value: {a: 'cool value' } },
  { valid: false, value: {bogus: 'cool value' } },
  { valid: false, value: {a: :symbol } },
  { valid: true, value: {a: 'cool value', c: {nested_b: 540} } },
  { valid: false, value: {a: 'cool value', c: {nested_b: :symbol} } },
  { valid: false, value: {a: 'cool value', c: {bogus: :symbol} } }
]

test_cases.each do |test_case|
  if test_case[:valid] == master_table.valid?(test_case[:value])
    puts "Good!"
  else
    puts ">>>#{test_case[:value]} was not #{test_case[:valid]}"
  end
end
```

The result of those tests are:

```
Good!
Good!
Good!
Good!
Good!
Good!
```

Now if it is the case that you *must* start with a hash in the form of `my_table` in your question, I'd still use `HashValidation` to perform the validation. In this case, you're problem is to transform `my_table` into as `HashValidation` object - a much more simple problem than you're trying to solve.

```
master_table_orig = {a: String, b: Object, c: { nested_a: Integer, nested_b: Integer} }

def create_hash_validation(hash)
  hash.inject({}) do |acc, (key, value)|
    acc[key] = if value.is_a?(Hash)
      HashValidation.new(create_hash_validation(hash[key]))
    else
      KlassValidation.new(value)
    end
    acc
  end
end
master_table = HashValidation.new(create_hash_validation(master_table_orig))
```

A major advantage of using validation classes is that you can now easily extend your solution. E.g., it would be simple to add a "required" option to a validation, as in `HashValidation.new(id: KlassValidation.new(Integer, required: true))`.